# Block IK bone rotation

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I have a problem, I want the hip bone (the upper one) not to rotate in the y axis. I only want the Shin bone to rotate when I move the small IK bone. I already tried with Limit Rotation and Inverse Kinematics but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Do you want "hip bone" (looks like what I'd call a thigh bone) to not rotate at all, or to only not rotate in the Y axis?

Comment: Only not to rotate in the Y axis